# Do not ask for confirmation when cancelling job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I just updated my Jenkins server to 2.32.2 and I noticed in the Release Notes that they added a feature which asks the user for confirmation before aborting a build (this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30565)

Is there a way to disable this feature? There are some cases where I have automated job cancellation using scripts and this new behavior would have an effect on all of those scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change only affects the browser interface. Any cancellation of builds via the Jenkins CLI or SSH interfaces, for example, would not be affected.